# Wamp codeigniter redirect with var dump

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some code in which I have a var_dump before I do a redirect

How do I change the settings in such a way that the var_dump will prevent the redirect?

Right now even though there is a var_dump there is still a redirect. But on my live website its showing the var_dump and not redirected. Is it some php settings or version?

Comment: Can you provide the code with which you are doing that pls ?

Comment: Without codes, no one can help.

Comment: Don't do var_dump before redirect and put `exit()` after `header()`.